разрядности переменных
для чего нужны 32, 16, 8 битные переменные, если есть 64. Я предпологаю что это попросту занимает больше памяти и замедляет работу программы, но также читал что не используемая память для переменных, просто отбрасывается в виде нулей. или же неиспользованная память которую мы выделили к примеру для longlong полностью выделяется для какого либо процесса, и из за этого его работа замедляется?

«отбрасывается в виде нулей» — тут какая-то чушь написана, 64 бита это всегда 64 бита. Конечно, можно придумать числа переменной длины, но да, работа с ними будет значительно медленнее

"Имя, сетра, имя?" Какой язык программирования? Числовые переменные?

@andreymal имеется ввиду нечно другое. Короткие данные всё равно хранятся блоками по 8 байтов, как, например, в .NET

В основном, экономия памяти, конечно. Это не для программ типа "Привет, мир!" Есть и другие вещи вроде векторных операций в процессоре.

@rotabor про .NET не знаю, но всякие низкоуровневые сишечки выделяют на числа ровно столько бит, сколько указано в их типе (хотя в структурах могут образоваться накладные расходы на padding)

@andreymal Да, это про паддинг. Понятно, что в массивах его нет.

Все верно - использование переменных разного размера (8, 16, 32, 64 бит) связано с эффективным управлением памятью и с производительностью программы. Вот основные причины, по которым существуют переменные разных размеров, и почему они до сих пор востребованы:

Экономия памяти
Меньшие переменные занимают меньше памяти, и это важно при работе с большими массивами или в системах с ограниченными ресурсами (например, встраиваемые системы, IoT-устройства, мобильные устройства). Если переменной достаточно 8 или 16 бит, использование 64-битного типа приведет к избыточному потреблению памяти.
В отличие от того, что вы читали, неиспользуемые биты не "обрезаются". Например, если вы создаете long long, система выделит 64-битный блок, даже если вам нужны только 8 бит.

Производительность и доступ к памяти
Многие процессоры используют кэш память, чтобы избежать простоев которые возникают при чтении из оперативной памяти. Большие переменные могут занимать больше места в кэше и замедлять доступ к другим данным.
При работе с массивами или структурами из меньших переменных кэш-память может вместить больше данных за один раз. Это улучшает производительность за счет снижения количества обращений к оперативной памяти.

Архитектурные ограничения
В некоторых системах, особенно на старых или специализированных устройствах, операции над 64-битными переменными требуют дополнительных шагов. В таких системах операции с 8, 16 и 32-битными переменными могут выполняться быстрее и эффективнее.

Стандарты и совместимость
В некоторых случаях программы требуют определенных размеров переменных для совместимости с форматом файла, сетевым протоколом или сторонними библиотеками, где строго определено, что данные передаются в 16 или 32-битном формате.


